# Lyft API giving invalid "no_service_in_area – The requested location is not inside a Lyft service area" when called from the iOS SDKs

Tags: lyft-api

The Lyft API is giving an invalid error when invoked from the iOS SDK on any of the ride type, estimates and ETA routes. Instead of giving back results, it errors saying there is no service in the area (Toronto, Canada).

EXAMPLE:
GET request to https://api.lyft.com/v1/eta?lat=43.6479328&lng=-79.3778371

ERROR:
`no_service_in_area`
`The requested location is not inside a Lyft service area`

**This is what the iOS SDK sends (BROKEN):**
[image]

When invoking the API manually (ie: Postman), the error goes away if the user agent which the SDK sends is omitted ('User-Agent' value of 'lyft-mobile-sdk:ios::1.0.6')

**Removing 'User-Agent' works:**
[image]

Confirmed that forking the iOS SDK and removing User-Agent removes this error (https://github.com/marchy/Lyft-iOS-sdk/commit/c23811f890e4881ef0e6789b6392b1a38db1334d) – thus the bug is on the API front.

**This affects all calls made from the iOS SDK** (at least up here in Canada – and perhaps other non-US regions).

BUG filed with iOS SDK here: https://github.com/lyft/Lyft-iOS-sdk/pull/19 – even though it's really an API bug (not sure if there's a better place to log it).

Comment: It is unclear what exactly you need to be resolved? What is your precise question?

Comment: Updated with more clarity, but basically API is broken for all requests made from the mobile SDKs in Canada (and perhaps other non-US regions as well). It returns an invalid error saying the service is not available within the area, but removing invoking the APIs manually without sending the User-Agent header returns the results as expected.